# How to pass max_token_to_sample parameter when using boto3 to access AWS bedrock model with Knowledgebase

Tags: large-language-model

I have this piece of code working to access AWS Bedrock models with a knowledge base:

```
    aws_session = boto3.Session(
    bedrock_agent_client = aws_session.client(service_name="bedrock-agent-runtime", region_name="us-west-2")
    response = bedrock_agent_client.retrieve_and_generate(
        input={"text": input_data},
        retrieveAndGenerateConfiguration={
            "type": "KNOWLEDGE_BASE",
            "knowledgeBaseConfiguration": {"knowledgeBaseId": config.bedrock.kb_id, "modelArn": model_arn},
        },
    )
    return response
```

However it uses default max_token_to_sample parameter which is rather small. boto3 client  retrieve_and_genenerate function does not seems to have a parameter or relevant config to specify it. Does anybody know how can I pass in this parameter? Thanks!